# Boolean tool won't work after several attempts to fix problem

Tags: modifiers

I'm a newbie and currently to create an organic shape. For this I wanted to use the Boolean tool but it is not working. I tried to "recalculate normals" but still it is not working. I also tried to simplify my object because I read that sometimes Boolean is not working properly if the structure is too complex. I am really frustrated and would be really grateful if someone could help me with that issue![image: This is how it looks like and it won't change.]

Comment: Select those red objects and search Recalculate Normals (or Shift+R) if still red go to Tool properties (left-down corner) and chech/uncheck toggle. Also after Boolen you have to hide original object, it is used as reference for boolean operation, so probably it was processed fine but result is blocked by reference object.

Comment: @vklidu I tried to recalculate and also tried to open tool properties but it won't open.  Do you have any ideas why it won't open?

Comment: @vklidu now all of a sudden the objects are all blue but still it doesn't cut out anything. The main object is a little bit more complex now but I still thought it should work if I recalculate the normals.

Comment: Did you hide object (seen red in your image)? If so share your file via https://blend-exchange.com to let us check.

Comment: @vklidu I tried to hide them but still it doesn't seem to work. Here is my file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jGNx7JKm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jGNx7JKm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me ... but to be clear - your topology is crazy ... there is no way to end up with something reasonable here ... this is result

[image]

without your Subdiv modifier (set to 6), that generates totally mad topology for boolean modifier, that I'm sure it has to collapse.

Here showcase with your subdivision just at Level 2 (so imagine 6 :) )

[image]

I highly recommend you to don't use n-gon for front back face.
Dirty way can be Triangulate + Remesh + Subdiv ...

[image]
... and there is not a reason to use for all Bevel modifiers such high value for segments (here used just 2).

For proper work you should care much more to base mesh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate just the red parts. When everything is blue it should work.

Comment: I tried to recalculate but nothing happens.. :(

Comment: Can you show your modifier setup and all the different object in your outliner?